# Структура БД, как правильно распределить контент и зависимости?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, веб-программирование, структуры-данных

В своем проекте я использую mysql, столкнулся с проблемой при проектировании некой структуры данных. Примерно как обстоят дела:

1. Например есть таблица articles, допустим у нее есть поля id, author_id, title, text, icons. (Здесь icons это integer, который содержит id ресурса о котором далее расскажу)
2. Есть таблица users, допустим с полями id, login, avatar. (Здесь поле avatar - это integer, который содержит id ресурса)
3. Есть таблица comments с полями id, article_id, author_id, date, text
4. Есть таблица resources, которая содержит поля id, type_id, files. (Здесь type_id - это integer который содержит id типа о котором далее, и files - содержит json строку, массив с именами картинок/файлов)
5. Есть таблица types, которая содержит поля id, params  и др. (params здесь, это json строка, которая содержит различные параметра ресурса, например это может быть адрес к директории в которой лежат картинки(ресурсы) соответствующие данному типу, и др. параметры)

Далее о проблеме. Например юзер заходит на страницу поста. Сначала нам нужно получить строку из таблицы articles с нужным id, тут же, мы хотим вывести данные об авторе поста, для этого нужно делать join таблицы users чтоб взять данные соответствующие полю author_id в таблице articles. Но, у юзера есть аватарка (поле avatar которое содержит id ресурса). Теперь нам нужно джоинить таблицу resources, здесь мы получаем список файлов в данном паке (поле files) и id типа этого ресурса (type_id) в котором лежат данные о ресурсе. Следующим шагом мы извлекаем данные типа (нам же нужно вывести картинку на странице, а тип содержит данные о том где лежит эта картинка и др параметры), и это еще один join.

Так мы распечатали пост, но у нас есть еще комменты, у которых есть id автора, а у автора есть аватарка, у аватарки есть ресурс с соответствующим типом, и это опять много джоинов.

Как видите, получается такая жесткая картина, с большим кол-вом сложных запросов. Задача - максимально упростить все.

P.S. Очень важно! Здесь я привел структуру на примере articles для доступного понимания проблемы, на самом деле проект очень громоздкий, именно из-за этого такая гора разбиений на типы, ресурсы и проч. параметры. И по поводу возможных советом по кэшированию, да, я понимаю что нужно кэшировать по возможности, но больший интерес у меня к совершенствованию данной структуры. Я думаю что многие из вас имеют опыт в больших/высоконагруженных проектах, разруливанию подобных ситуаций, поэтому очень надеюсь на ваши советы.

Comment: Можно в users положить поле с url картинки, который будет вычисляться и сохранятся триггерами на resurses и types. Вот как раз кеш и получается

Comment: @Mike, да, но может быть такой случай, когда 1 ресурс (картинка), может соответствовать (быть прикрепленным) к нескольким записям из разных таблиц. И собственно этот вариант я обдумывал, пока ни к чему, на эту тему, еще не пришел

Comment: сложный запрос с множеством join'ов можно определить как view или stored procedure

Comment: @Stack, я не совсем пойму как это можно применить к моему случаю, можете привести конкретный пример?